# mysql starts and stops servers automatically non stop

Tags: mysql, mac-os-x

I am working on macOS High Sierra.

Basically, the problem is that for some reason the mysql server is starting and stopping automatically, and constantly. It does not stop. If I run:

```
# ps -ax | grep mysql
```

to see the processes even when I (think) I have uninstalled mysql, it shows:

```
54948 ttys002    0:00.00 grep mysql
```

I run the same thing 5 seconds later, and it has a different ID:

```
54950 ttys002    0:00.00 grep mysql
```

I cannot `sudo kill -9 54950` because by the time I try to kill it, it has already disappeared.

I have tried removing everything related to mysql. I then reinstall it, and the same thing happens. I have tried doing this with homebrew as well.

Please help.

Comment: What is in mysql's log files?

Answer (score 1):

You are not seeing any mysql processes.
You are seeing your own `grep` process, as it is *looking for* mysql processes.

To avoid this, try this:

```
ps -ef | grep mysql | grep -v $$
```

The "$$" in the second grep is expanded (by the shell) into the current command's `pid`, effectively filtering this out of the `ps` results (so you'd get an empty result).

> ... mysql server is starting and stopping automatically, and constantly.

Look in the mysql server log and see why it's "stopping" or, perhaps, not even starting.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you will see your terminal running the grep command .. that's pretty much to be expected. Please learn some console basics (either mac os or free bsd related  as that is the underlaying system that mac os builds on )

If ps -> grep really only shows its own instance then there is nothing else with "mysql" in its process name. 
Which pretty much explains that you cant kill the process afterwards - because the console-command did its work and then the process ended regularly. Hence your second attempt "generated" a new process ID (new process) ...

At the time of your ps -> grep NO "other" mysql process is running.